# Scraping a PDF with ScraperWiki and getting an Error of not Defined

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.x, scraperwiki

I am trying to scrape this PDF with ScraperWiki.  The current code gives me an error of name 'data' is not defined but I receive the error on

```
elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 647: data['Neighborhood'] = el.text
```

If i comment that line out i get the same error on my else statement.

Here is my code

```
import scraperwiki
import urllib2, lxml.etree
#Pull Mondays
url = 'http://www.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/police/blotter/blotter_monday.pdf'
pdfdata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
xmldata = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfdata)
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmldata)
# how many pages in PDF
pages = list(root)
print "There are",len(pages),"pages"
# Test Scrape of only Page 1 of 29
for page in pages[0:1]:
    for el in page:
        if el.tag == "text":
            if int(el.attrib['left']) < 11: data = { 'Report Name': el.text }
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 317: data['Location of Occurrence'] = el.text
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 169: data['Incident Time'] = el.text
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 647: data['Neighborhood'] = el.text
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 338: data['Description'] = el.text
            else:
                data['Zone'] = el.text
                print data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also any suggestions of a better solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've skipped some of your code, your `data` dictionary only gets created **if** the condition in this line is matched:

`if int(el.attrib['left']) < 11: data = { 'Report Name': el.text }`

All of your other lines where you set values in `data` depend on it already existing, so you'll get the `NameError` if this first condition isn't matched.

The quick fix would be to *always* create an empty data dictionary, e.g.

```
for page in pages[0:1]:
    for el in page:
        data = {}
        if el.tag =="text":
```

etc.